# Can I know the file and function names from where my function is called if it's from another .c?

Tags: c, debugging, c-preprocessor, instrumentation

I'm developing a library and I would like to know some data about the caller of one of the functions I'm offering. In particular, I would need to know the file name, function name and line where my function (a redefined malloc) is being called.

EDIT: Here's a minimum working example where I can detect when a user calls malloc and "redirect" him to my own malloc function:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myLib.h"

int main(){
    printf("Inside main, asking for memory\n");

    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 3;

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

myLib.c:

```
#include "myLib.h"

void * myAlloc (size_t size){
    void * p = NULL;

    fprintf(stderr, "Inside my own malloc\n");
    
    p = (malloc)(size);

    return p;
    
}
#undef malloc
#define malloc(size) myAlloc(size)
```

myLib.h:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define malloc(size) myAlloc(size)

void * myAlloc(size_t size);
#endif
```

I've tried using _*FILE*_ _*func*_ and _*LINE*_ keywords, but I can't make it work since it's in a different module.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] that compiles except for the error that you are referring to in your question.

Comment: `#define malloc(size)` produces a syntax error: `void *p = ;`

Comment: then why variadic macro here: `#define malloc(size, ...) myMalloc (size, __FILE__)` should be `#define malloc(size) myMalloc (size, __FILE__)`

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @wobr I edited my post with a basic example, Thanks!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually adding the "...· when redefining malloc was a not so successful try to fix the error that said "expected declaration or specifier"

Comment: @thebusybee I'm trying to detect when the user makes a certain error and give him information about where he made it.

Comment: Just use `assert()`. When the user runs their code in a debugger, the program will be stopped and they can inspect a backtrace. The other alternative violates principles of encapsulation, the code shouldn't care where it is called from.

Comment: @Guillem maybe you can [edit] your question removing obsolete input (like the "..." arguments) because now your question is in 2 parts and is unclear

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Done. Cheers!

Comment: `#undef malloc
#define malloc(size) myAlloc(size)` is useless. `malloc.h` is non-strandard part of glibc, of you are using glibc you might as well [follow the documentation on replacing malloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

```
//mylib.h
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include <stdlib.h>
// replace malloc in case it's already a macro
#ifdef malloc
#undef malloc
#endif

// I believe that from the standards point of view, this is undefined behavior
#define malloc(size) my_alloc(size, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__)

#ifdef __GNUC__
// Allow compiler to do static checking.
__attribute__((__alloc_size__(1), __malloc__))
#endif
void *my_alloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func);
//    ^^^^^^^^ I do not like camelCase case - one snake case to rule them all.

#endif

// mylib.c
#include "mylib.h" // do not ever mix uppercase and lowercase in filenames
#undef malloc      // undef malloc so we don't call ourselves recursively
#include <stdio.h>

void *my_alloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func){
    fprintf(stderr, "Och my god, you wouldn't believe it!\n"
          "A function %s in file %s at line %d called malloc!\n",
         func, file, line);
    return malloc(size);
}
```

You might also see how [assert does it](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/assert/assert.h.html). If you are aiming at glibc, read [glibc docs replacing malloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html).

Still as you discovered a user may do `(malloc)(size)` cicumvent macro expansion. You could do:

```
void *my_alloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line, const char *func);

static inline void *MY_ALLOC(size_t size) {
    return my_alloc(size, NULL, 0, NULL);
}
#define MY_ALLOC(size)  my_alloc(size, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__)

// if called with `malloc()` then MY_ALLOC is expanded
// if called as `(malloc)`, then just expands to MY_ALLOC.
#define malloc MY_ALLOC

int main() {
    malloc(10);    // calls my_alloc(10, "main.c", 62, "main");
    (malloc)(20);  // calls my_alloc(20, NULL, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: adding the size (and possibly the result) of malloc to the trace is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

GLIBC defines hidden symbols for malloc(), free()... which are called __libc_malloc(), __libc_free()...

So, you can tremendously simplify your debug macros.

In **m.h**, just define the following:

```
#if DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

extern void *__libc_malloc (size_t bytes);

extern void *myMalloc(size_t size, const char *filename, const char *funcname, int line);

#define malloc(size) myMalloc(size, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__)

#endif
```

Then you can write a program defining myMalloc() as follow (e.g. file name is **m.c**):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "m.h"

#if DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

void *myMalloc(
              size_t      size,
              const char *filename,
              const char *funcname,
              int         line
             ) {

  fprintf(stderr, "malloc(%zu) called from %s/%s()#%d\n", size, filename, funcname, line);

  return __libc_malloc(size);
}

#endif

char *dup_str(char *string) {

  char *str = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);

  strcpy(str, string);

  return str;
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {

  char *str;

  if (av[1]) {
    str = dup_str(av[1]);
  } else {
    str = dup_str("NULL");
  }

  printf("String = '%s'\n", str);

  free(str);

  return 0;
}
```

When you compile this example program in non debug mode:

```
$ gcc m.c -DDEBUG_LEVEL=0
$ ./a.out azerty
String = 'azerty'
```

When you compile your program in debug mode:

```
$ gcc m.c -DDEBUG_LEVEL=1
$ ./a.out azerty
malloc(7) called from m.c/dup_str()#27
String = 'azerty'
```